# why bcryptjs compare gives null value even though hash used is generated one?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, hash, bcrypt

FOr authentication purpose, I'm storing the hashed password in MongoDB when I try to compare this password for the same string  bcryptjs throws a null value.
[image: database image]

where it stores hashed password in Binary form for string '123'.
here is my generating code

```
import bcrypt
salt = bcrypt.gensalt()    
password = bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'), salt)
```

When I try to compare this with user entered password '123' I get a null value.

```
123 $2b$12$URN6pyD4SsOgIXALvr.jIuy2hvxlxva.ioamDNtMhAwvWb9/nLdhO null
```

here is my nodejs code with bcryptjs to compare user password with hashed database password

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (passw, cb) {
    var user = this;
    console.log((passw === user.password) ? 'passwords match' : 'passwords dont match' );
    console.log(passw +" "+ user.password )
    bcrypt.compare(passw, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        console.log(passw +" "+ user.password +" " +isMatch )
        if(err) {
            return cb(err)
        }
        cb(null, isMatch)
    })
}
```

I get a null value even though I enter the same string '123' also If I try checking with this online bcryptchecker website https://bcryptgenerator.com/ I get a match. What am I doing wrong exactly here?can someone point out my mistake ?

Comment: for generating I'm  using python bcrypt and saving it in the database and for checking I'm using bcrypt compare. Check edited question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making the mistake in sending data to 'bcrypt.compare' method. You should make changes:

```
bcrypt.compare(user.password, 'password from database')
    .then(status => console.log(status))
    .catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
     }
```

For more details check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs).

Comment: nope, I''m sending in right order which is user entered password followed by hashed password from databse